# Buying a PUT OPTION in the Out Of The Money

Tags: options, put-options

The scenario is this. The price of a XYZ stock is **$150**. I speculate that the stock price can go to **$200** and then retreat to **$160** in six months. Is it possible to buy a **PUT OPTION** at strike price **$199** that expires in six months, and then sell it when the price reaches **$160** before the expiration date and make a profit of **199 - 160** = 39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you an example.

You said current price $150 but at $199 (we will use $200 strike because strike prices comes in increments) you want to buy a put when stock is at $200 and sell the put when the stock is at $160.

So fast forward....the stock is $200:

6 month put COST: $17.50 @ 200 strike (costs $1,750 per contract)

(remember the strike price is where you exercise or collect your shares whether its a call/+shares or put/-shares.

By 6 months: stock is $160

Profit Formula: (strike price) - (current price) - (options cost) + (remaining time value)

Profit formula: $200-$160 = $40 - $17.50 = $22.50 profit + ($1-2 time value) (you can add $1-2 time value if you sold after 3 months and option has 3 months time value left)

Basically you put in $1,750 it became $4,000 and your profit is $2,250 for a 128.5% profit ($22.50/$17.50).

Any questions?

Comment: Apart from your overly optimistic $2 time value projection for 3 months remaining until expiration when the option is $40 in-the-money, you might want to redo your calculations.  $200 - $160 - $17.50 isn't $12.50

Comment: @BobBaerker thanks bob i edited my answer should be $22.50 :) Nice catch!